# Django Two Factor Auth combined with Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, two-factor-authentication, totp, django-two-factor-auth

I'm trying to implement [django two factor auth](https://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.io/en/1.14.0/) into my Rest API. Is there a possibility to implement this by using custom views and model creations? Because, at least that's the way I understood it, this library is mainly working based on default django templates and predefined routes.
Is it possible to combine this library with a Rest API or should I use another library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cam use [pyotp](https://pyauth.github.io/pyotp/) library. It's compatible with most of the two factor authenticator app like google authenticator. Very easy to use.

Here is an example how to use use:

```
base32 = pyotp.random_base32() 
>>> base32
'ERAAADLXLDFBVL2JSR4RLR73DWFWYSTU'
>>> totp = pyotp.TOTP(base32)
>>> totp.now() 
'206328'
```

It will generate random code after every 30 seconds. For generate provisioning URIs for use with the QR Code scanner:

```
pyotp.totp.TOTP('ERAAADLXLDFBVL2JSR4RLR73DWFWYSTU').provisioning_uri(name='alice@google.com', issuer_name='Secure App')
>>> 'otpauth://totp/Secure%20App:alice%40google.com?secret=ERAAADLXLDFBVL2JSR4RLR73DWFWYSTU&issuer=Secure%20App'
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems indeed quite simple. I'll see if I can get it implemented with my JWT authentication backend :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a package for Django REST 2FA:
https://github.com/merixstudio/django-trench

Comment: I took a look at it and it seems that trench also provides endpoints for login returning e.g. JWT tokens. Do you know if it's possible to implement django-trench into an already existing JWT authentication system? There's also the problem that the login endpoint only takes a username & password while my already existing system supports username and email logins.